# Latest Datepicker jquery-ui-1.10.0 issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a datepicker which on clicking the date I'm doing some stuffs. This was working when I was using the older jQuery UI version but after upgrading to the latest version I'm getting the issue. If you inspect the datepicker you will see that every cell has class 'ui-state-default' which is the one that I'm clicking on.

$(document).on("click", ".ui-state-default", function(){

```
alert("Inside");
```

});

This click events doesn't work now with the latest jQueryUI.

I'm using the latest jQuery and the jQuery UI.

- jquery-1.9.1.min.js
- jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.js

Can anybody help me out on this?

Comment: What did you use before this version? Was it "click" or "live" ?

Comment: Yes, Live is deprecated now in the latest versions of jQuery. and ON doesn't look for elements that don't yet exist in the DOM, therefore if you want to use your function it would have to be in a callback after the datepicker is opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this would work. Mind you I haven't tested this with the latest versions:

```
$( ".dateselector" ).datepicker({ onSelect: function(){ 
 alert('Hey You Clicked Me!');
} });
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to do but why don't you just do something like this? Basically chain the `click` on the actual `input` itself instead of attaching it to another `UI` element.

```
$('.dateBox').datepicker().click(function(){
    alert("yo");
});
```